# Checking if either two values is negative

Tags: javascript

I have two values, lets name it first value and second value. 
I'm trying to validate if either of them is negative. One of the two values must be negative or the two values are negative. I am using javascript here. So there are two arrays of values. I tried to concat the values and used a reg exp to check if there is a negative sign, but only the first value is being validated. Any idea for this?

```
for(var i=0; i<first_value.length;i++)
      {

          var getVals = first_value[i].value + " " + second_value[i].value;
          if(!getVals[i].match(/-/g) )
          {
              err2[i].innerHTML = "Atleast one negative!";
              alert(getVals);
              return false;  
          }


      }
```

Comment: Why not just do `if (first_value[i].value >= 0 && second_value[i].value >= 0)` ? Testing the mathematical value of a number with a regular expression seems... wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return first_value > 0 && second_value > 0`

Comment: Should be `||` instead of '&&'.

Comment: @Aashray why? it will only return true if both are positive. if one is negative, false.

Comment: @Aashray: The OP actually wants to test whether both values are positive and show an error message if they are. Check their code.

Comment: @Aashray I am checking the code and it seems pretty clear that they intend to shout "Atleast one negative!" and return false when one value is negative.

Comment: && is the answer, when I used || when the second value is negative, and the first value is positive, it return false.

Comment: Mistook the greater than symbol for `<`. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
if(first_value[i].value < 0 || second_value[i].value < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<first_value.length;i++)
  {

     if (first_value[i].value < -1 || second_value[i].value < -1)
      {
          err2[i].innerHTML = "Atleast one negative!";
          alert(getVals);
          return false;  
      }


  }
```

Comment: Heh, still wrong :) `<= 0` tests for "zero or negative", not for "negative". `< 0` tests for "negative".

Comment: That's not equivalent to what the OP currently has.